# Dynamically viewing Python script results in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, idle

I want to view the output of ArcPy scripts (run in Python IDLE) in ArcMap.

I tried refreshing the ArcMap data frame after I run the script.

This does not work. Please advise me on this?

Comment: Are you saving the map document in your code before refreshing?

Comment: Changes to the data should work either way, but if you change the extent you'd have to save the map document.

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether your script changes underlying data (if you try to do that while ArcMap is open I think you'll encounter a lock) or map properties.  If you can [edit] your question to provide a code snippet then it will be much easier to try and advise.

Answer (score 7):

Run your Python scripts in the built in Python window in ArcMap.  Changes will be displayed if you make references to the ["CURRENT" map document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000000r000000).

[image: Python Window in ArcGIS]

[Refresh active view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000051000000) will help if you're interested in changing the extent, otherwise layers are generally added to the map automatically [with the exception of feature layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/add-feature-layer-to-display-with-in-a-script-tool-for-desktop-mapping-app).

Comment: I recommend clipping the image. As it is now it's a 90% white and featureless block and the actual area of interest is not legible.